# Overload resolution of template functions

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

//Number1
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
    std::cout << "auto max(T1 a, T2 b)" <<std::endl;
    return  b < a ? a : b;
}

//Number2
template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
    std::cout << "RT max(T1 a, T2 b)" << std::endl;
    return  b < a ? a : b;
}


int main()
{
    auto a = ::max(4, 7.2);         //Select Number1

    auto b = ::max<double>(4, 7.4); //Select Number2

    auto c = ::max<int>(7, 4.);     //Compile-time error overload ambiguous

    auto c = ::max<double>(7, 4.); //Select Number2

}
```

`auto c = ::max<int>(7, 4.);` : This line fails to compile because of overload ambiguity with the following message:

```
maxdefault4.cpp:9:27: error: call of overloaded 'max(int, double)' is ambiguous
  auto c = ::max<int>(7, 4.);
                           ^
maxdefault4.cpp:9:27: note: candidates are:
In file included from maxdefault4.cpp:1:0:
maxdefault4.hpp:4:6: note: auto max(T1, T2) [with T1 = int; T2 = double]
 auto max (T1 a, T2 b)
      ^
maxdefault4.hpp:11:4: note: RT max(T1, T2) [with RT = int; T1 = int; T2 = double]
 RT max (T1 a, T2 b)
    ^
```

while the following code:
`àuto c = ::max<double>(7, 4.)` succeed, why don't we have the same error message saying the call is amgiguous for `max<double>` the same the way `max<int>` failed ?

Why for `double` there's no problem ?

I've read in "C++ templates, the completes Guide" book that the template argument deduction does not take the return type into account, so why `max<int>` is ambiguous and not `max<double>`?

Does the return type of a template function really not taken into account in argument dedcution ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> the template argument deduction does not take the return type into account,

Yes. [Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is performed based on function arguments.

> so why `max<int>` is ambiguous and not `max<double>`?

Given `::max<int>(7, 4.)`, for the 1st overload, the 1st template parameter `T1` is specified as `int`, and `T2` is deduced as `double` from the 2nd function argument `4.`, then the instantiation would be **`double max(int, double)`**. For the 2nd overload, the 1st template parameter `RT` is specified as `int`, `T1` is deduced as `int` from `7`, `T2` is deduced as `double` from `4.`, then the instantiation would be **`int max(int, double)`**. [Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) doesn't consider return type too, the two overloads are both **exact match** and then ambiguous.

Given `::max<double>(7, 4.)`, for the 1st overload, the 1st template parameter `T1` is specified as `double`, and `T2` is deduced as `double` from `4.`, so the instantiation would be **`double max(double, double)`**. For the 2nd overload, the 1st template parameter `RT` is specified as `double`, `T1` is deduced as `int` from `7`, `T2` is deduced as `double` from `4.`, then the instantiation would be **`double max(int, double)`**. Then the 2nd overload wins in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) because it's an **exact match**, the 1st one requires the **implicit conversion** from `int` to `double` for the 1st argument `7`.

Answer (score 3):

For each of your function calls the compiler has 2 functions to choose from and chooses the best one. Unknown template parameters are deduced from the arguments apart from `RT` which must be explicitly specified and can't be deduced.

```
auto a = ::max(4, 7.2);
```

As `RT` is not specified and can't be deduced, the second overload is not usable so is ignored. The first is chosen and the types are deduced as `int` and `double`.

```
auto b = ::max<double>(4, 7.4);
```

`RT` is now specified so the compiler can choose to either use `max<double,int,double>` or `max<double, double>`, the argument types for the 3 template parameter version match the function arguments exactly whereas the 2 template parameter version would require a cast from `int` to `double` so the 3 parameter overload is chosen.

```
auto c = ::max<int>(7, 4.);
```

`RT` is now specified so the compiler can choose to either use `max<int,int,double>` or `max<int, double>`, the argument types both functions are now the same so the compiler can't choose between them.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what specifying `double` as an argument does for the compiler during overload resolution.

For the "Number1" `max` template, it specifies that the first argument must be of type `double`. When attempting to do the template match, the compiler deduces that the second argument is of type `double`. So the resultant signature is `auto max(double, double)`. That's a match, though it involves casting the first argument from `int` to `double`.

For the "Number2" `max` template, it specifies that the return type is `double`. The argument types are deduced. So the resultant signature is `double max(int, double)`. That's an exact match, removing any ambiguity.

Now let's look at specifying `int`. Now the two signatures are `auto max(int, double)` and `double max(int, double)`. As you can see, there's no difference which is relevant to overload resolution, resulting in the ambiguity.

Essentially, by passing in `double`, you've poisoned one of the overloads by forcing an unnecessary conversion; the other overload thereby gets to dominate. Passing in `int`, in contrast, does not further constrain either overload's ability to be a perfect match.